# How to check if aptitude did something?

Tags: compiling, make, aptitude

I've a CI build process during which I install a debian package from my local reprepro.

I have a `Makefile` which does call aptitude to install the package from its own repository like this

```
sudo aptitude -y install foobar >> aptitude.log 2>&1
```

Now it could happen that aptitude has conflicts, which can't be resolved or the repository doesn't offer a new version for the package "foobar". In both cases aptitude wouldn't install anything.
But

```
echo $?
```

after the aptitude call in the `Makefile` always returns `0`.
What way do you propose to check if aptitude actually did install anything? Grepping for the last line of the aptitude output is the only thing I can think of if the exit codes are always `0`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try with `dpkg-query`, which print information about installed package

Exemple:

```
dpkg-query -W -f='${Status} ${Version}\n' foobar
```

Will result

```
No packages found matching foobar.
```

Run `dpkg-query --help` for more information

Comment: that's really good, I'm just going to call that command before and after the aptitude and will compare the different status and version. thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you want to check that an install (and not an upgrade) has gone well, you can count the number of files in `/var/lib/dpkg/info` before and after the `aptitude` run. This is not particularly robust, though.